# DHT22 Sensor + pi4j + java

Tags: java, pi4j

[read temperature from DHT11, using pi4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486159/read-temperature-from-dht11-using-pi4j)

I the tried the code in the following link with prerequisites :

Java 1.8.0_65

pi4j 1.1

Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

DHT22 Temperature sensor.

Here when I am trying to execute the following both codes available in the link I am facing the issue regarding the `LibPins` in the code

```
public DHT11(int pin) {

final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

dht11Pin = gpio.provisionDigitalMultipurposePin(LibPins.getPin(pin),

 PinMode.DIGITAL_INPUT, PinPullResistance.PULL_UP);

}
```

and in the other code snippet I am getting the output as "Data not good,Skip"
But for the second code in the link I was getting the output for few set of readings and after its outputting as "Data not good,Skip".

I am working on reading the temperature connected to pi gpio pins using java and pi4j library.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The page https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=81&t=91896 reports problems with reading the sensor with pi4j. Seems to be a timing problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck with this (modified from another thread). 
You'll also need to install wiring pi `sudo apt-get install wiringpi`
It should be noted that this I put this class into it's own thread and loop it by calling run(). It then stuffs the variables into local state and I can reference them in my main class.

```
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.GpioUtil;

public class DHT22 implements Runnable {
    private static final int maxTimings = 85;
    private final int[] dht22_dat = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private float temperature = 9999;
    private float humidity = 9999;
    boolean shuttingDown = false;


    public DHT22() {
        // setup wiringPi
        if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
            System.out.println(" ==>> GPIO SETUP FAILED");
            return;
        }
        GpioUtil.export(3, GpioUtil.DIRECTION_OUT);
    }

    private int pollDHT22() {
        int lastState = Gpio.HIGH;
        int j = 0;
        dht22_dat[0] = dht22_dat[1] = dht22_dat[2] = dht22_dat[3] = dht22_dat[4] = 0;

        int pinNumber = 16;
        Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.OUTPUT);
        Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.LOW);
        Gpio.delay(18);

        Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.HIGH);
        Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.INPUT);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxTimings; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            while (Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == lastState) {
                counter++;
                Gpio.delayMicroseconds(1);
                if (counter == 255) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            lastState = Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber);

            if (counter == 255) {
                break;
            }

            /* ignore first 3 transitions */
            if (i >= 4 && i % 2 == 0) {
                /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
                dht22_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
                if (counter > 16) {
                    dht22_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return j;

    }

    private void refreshData() {
        int pollDataCheck = pollDHT22();
        if (pollDataCheck >= 40 && checkParity()) {

            final float newHumidity = (float) ((dht22_dat[0] << 8) + dht22_dat[1]) / 10;
            final float newTemperature = (float) (((dht22_dat[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + dht22_dat[3]) / 10;

            if (humidity == 9999 || ((newHumidity < humidity + 40) && (newHumidity > humidity - 40))) {
                humidity = newHumidity;
                if (humidity > 100) {
                    humidity = dht22_dat[0]; // for DHT22
                }
            }

            if (temperature == 9999 || ((newTemperature < temperature + 40) && (newTemperature > temperature - 40))) {
                temperature = (float) (((dht22_dat[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + dht22_dat[3]) / 10;
                if (temperature > 125) {
                    temperature = dht22_dat[2]; // for DHT22
                }
                if ((dht22_dat[2] & 0x80) != 0) {
                    temperature = -temperature;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    float getHumidity() {
        if (humidity == 9999) {
            return 0;
        }
        return humidity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    float getTemperature() {
        if (temperature == 9999) {
            return 0;
        }
        return temperature;
    }

    float getTemperatureInF() {
        if (temperature == 9999) {
            return 32;
        }
        return temperature * 1.8f + 32;
    }

    private boolean checkParity() {
        return dht22_dat[4] == (dht22_dat[0] + dht22_dat[1] + dht22_dat[2] + dht22_dat[3] & 0xFF);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!shuttingDown) {
            refreshData();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This version uses the java nanosecond timing to read the binary data. It uses Pi4J which uses WiringPi. I hope it is helpful.  (https://github.com/dougculnane/java-pi-thing)

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

import com.pi4j.io.gpio.Pin;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.RaspiPin;
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Gpio;

/**
 * Implements the DHT22 / AM2302 reading in Java using Pi4J.
 * 
 * See (AM2302.pdf) specksheet for details of timings.
 *
 * @author Doug Culnane
 */
public class DHT22 {

    /**
     * Time in nanoseconds to separate ZERO and ONE signals.
     */
    private static final int LONGEST_ZERO = 50000;

    /**
     * PI4J Pin number.
     */
    private int pinNumber;

    /**
     * 40 bit Data from sensor
     */
    private byte[] data = null;

    /**
     * Value of last successful humidity reading.
     */
    private Double humidity = null;

    /**
     * Value of last successful temperature reading.
     */
    private Double temperature = null;

    /**
     * Last read attempt
     */
    private Long lastRead = null;

    /**
     * Constructor with pin used for signal.  See PI4J and WiringPI for
     * pin numbering systems.....
     *
     * @param pin
     */
    public DHT22(Pin pin) {
        pinNumber = pin.getAddress();
    }

    /**
     * Communicate with sensor to get new reading data.
     *
     * @throws Exception if failed to successfully read data.
     */
    private void getData() throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ReadSensorFuture readSensor = new ReadSensorFuture();
        Future<byte[]> future = executor.submit(readSensor);
        // Reset data
        data = new byte[5];
        try {
            data = future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            readSensor.close();
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            readSensor.close();
            future.cancel(true);
            executor.shutdown();
            throw e;
        }
        readSensor.close();
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    /**
     * Make a new sensor reading.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public boolean read() throws Exception {
        checkLastReadDelay();
        lastRead = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getData();
        checkParity();
        humidity = getReadingValueFromBytes(data[0], data[1]);
        temperature = getReadingValueFromBytes(data[2], data[3]);
        lastRead = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return true;
    }

    private void checkLastReadDelay() throws Exception {
        if (Objects.nonNull(lastRead)) {
            if (lastRead > System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000) {
                throw new Exception("Last read was under 2 seconds ago. Please wait longer between reads!");
            }
        }
    }

    private double getReadingValueFromBytes(final byte hi, final byte low) {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        bb.put(hi);
        bb.put(low);
        short shortVal = bb.getShort(0);
        return new Double(shortVal) / 10;
    }

    private void checkParity() throws ParityChheckException {
        if (!(data[4] == (data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3] & 0xFF))) {
            throw new ParityChheckException();
        }
    }

    public Double getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public Double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    /**
     * Run from command line to loop and make readings.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Starting DHT22");
        if (Gpio.wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
            System.out.println("GPIO wiringPiSetup Failed!");
            return;
        }

        DHT22 dht22 = new DHT22(RaspiPin.GPIO_05);
        int LOOP_SIZE = 10;
        int countSuccess = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < LOOP_SIZE; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                System.out.println();
                dht22.read();
                System.out.println("Humidity=" + dht22.getHumidity() + 
                        "%, Temperature=" + dht22.getTemperature() + "*C");

                countSuccess++;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Read success rate: "+ countSuccess + " / " + LOOP_SIZE);
        System.out.println("Ending DHT22");
    }

    /**
     * Callable Future for reading sensor.  Allows timeout if it gets stuck.
     */
    private class ReadSensorFuture implements Callable<byte[]>, Closeable {

        private boolean keepRunning = true;

        public ReadSensorFuture() {
            Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.OUTPUT);
            Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.HIGH);
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] call() throws Exception {

            // do expensive (slow) stuff before we start.       
            byte[] data = new byte[5];
            long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 

            sendStartSignal();
            waitForResponseSignal();
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
                while (keepRunning && Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == Gpio.LOW) {
                }
                startTime = System.nanoTime();    
                while (keepRunning && Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == Gpio.HIGH) {
                }
                long timeHight = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                data[i / 8] <<= 1;
                if ( timeHight > LONGEST_ZERO) {
                    data[i / 8] |= 1;
                }
            }
            return data;
        }

        private void sendStartSignal() {
            // Send start signal.
            Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.OUTPUT);
            Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.LOW);
            Gpio.delay(1);
            Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.HIGH);
        }

        /**
         * AM2302 will pull low 80us as response signal, then 
         * AM2302 pulls up 80us for preparation to send data.
         */
        private void waitForResponseSignal() {
            Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.INPUT);
            while (keepRunning && Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == Gpio.HIGH) {
            }
            while (keepRunning && Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == Gpio.LOW) {
            }
            while (keepRunning && Gpio.digitalRead(pinNumber) == Gpio.HIGH) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            keepRunning = false;

            // Set pin high for end of transmission.
            Gpio.pinMode(pinNumber, Gpio.OUTPUT);
            Gpio.digitalWrite(pinNumber, Gpio.HIGH);
        }
    }

    private class ParityChheckException extends Exception {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    }

}
```